# What's the best way to manage different versions of the same library in a .Net application?

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I am trying to find a way to use multiple versions of the same library in my .NET application. My main goal with this exercise is to support new releases without having to update my application every time a new version of a library is released.

Here is a very simple use case example using a utility library:

I have created two versions of an Amazon Utility to upload documents to the AWS S3 bucket with different versions of AWSSDK.S3 nuget package with other versions very likely to follow.

[image]

Main challenge:

- Both these libraries have a dependency on different versions of AWSSDK.Core.dll and AWSSDK.S3.dll
- Both these libraries also have a dependency on the same version of some shared libraries i.e. Newtonssoft.Json and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
- Users in my .Net application should have the option of using any version of lib. E.g. User A will use the v1 of the utility to build their process and UserB uses v2 of the utility.

I cannot drop both these libraries into the bin folder of my .Net application because you cannot have two files with the same name.

I could put them in separate folders but would that mean I also need to include all shared dlls i.e. Newtonsosft and Logging dlls.

As we can download different versions of a Nuget package, could this be used to manage these packages? I.e. I keep all shared dlls in my bin folder and use the nuget package manager to load the correct version of the nuget package.

Any other way to manage this use case?

Comment: It is actually more complicated than file(names). Read up on [AppDomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain), if you are using the .NET Framework / Desktop CLR, or on [AssemblyLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext), if you are using .NET / CoreCLR.

Comment: Alternatively, you could consider putting the functionality that uses the DLL in quesion into a separate process/executable. Than have multiple of those, and from your application launch the one with the desired version. You need then need some sort of IPC to communicate with this external process (STDIN, STDOUT might be enough, but you would have to provide more info to be sure).

Comment: You can try to solve this by [extern aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias), though it will not help if the deeper dependencies also reference incompatible versions of some packages.

Comment: Solution:

AppDomain had performance and memory-related complications so after a long search, I found that [strong naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/strong-named) assemblies were the right solution.

I kept all strong-named assemblies in different folders as keeping different files with the same name in a folder is impossible. I had to programmatically load the main assembly, after that it automatically pulled the correct dependencies from different folders.

Answer (score 0):

If the libraries use semantic versioning and have the same major version you can use assembly binding redirects to load the latest version of an assembly. This will then be used by all assemblies in the process, even if they reference an older version. This can help solve some, but not all problems.

The general problem is just difficult to solve. Multiple versions of the same library means multiple conflicting definitions of a class, and this can easily result in conflicts. John skeet has a pair of articles discussing the problems and possible solutions:

- [Versioning limitations in .NET](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/06/30/versioning-limitations-in-net/)
- [Options for .NET’s versioning issues](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/10/25/options-for-nets-versioning-issues/)

But I do not think any of the suggestions have been adopted yet.

A workaround could be to use appdomains or separate processes to separate your libraries. This way you would likely handle potential conflicts when serializing your data.

Comment: I handled this using AppDomain and lots of proxy classes. Even though its a very old module it did the job for me. Using .NetFramework472 also didn't leave me with lots of other options.

The other options were microservice, embedding dependencies as resources, or including the version number in the library's name. This along with assembly binding would have solved the issue for me.